# Git Push failed: fatal: unable to access Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805

Tags: android, git, curl, ssl, github

I sync my projects to GitHub with Android Studio.

[image]

[image]

After adding several files, I tried to commit and push. Committing produced no errors, but I was unable to push

I received this error:

```
9:40:41 AM Push failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805
9:41:37 AM 1 file committed: -sharedpreferences attempt 9002
           checkbox
9:43:40 AM Push failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805
```

I did some research from I am unable to produce a solution that will work for me.

[Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection)

http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

How can I fix this?

Here is what I obtained after `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2890 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 6FF41C622CD9C0BCA1E39A6A266DE94AC91B4343D50845AE4765CA6A62D42AE5
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: A3885EE106E5D99F6FA884DC35C94ABA5C73965613168E82F9E9733C7B433A3BD2C17802FA91E396AE901D47D553B0D2
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1407856220
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

Comment: The `-9805` looks like you are on OS X (I think that's a `SecureTransport` error code). Is that the case?

Comment: GitHub uses DigiCert as the CA. Specifically, the site is certified by `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA`. That CA is part of Mac OS X trusted store; see [OS X Mavericks: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6005). Does your organization use an SSL/TLS interception proxy or other proxy? Update your question and post the results of `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443`.

Comment: Okay. I am having some trouble obtaining the results of that. how do I obtain the result?

Comment: CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private

Comment: Organization/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/serialNumber=5157550/street=548 4th Street/postalCode=94107/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=GitHub, Inc./CN=github.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---

---

Comment: I'll just post it in my question

Comment: That is weird. That's the expected output from `s_client`, so I don't see anything wrong. Actually, there's one small thing wrong: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`.  You should *not* have gotten that result because I did *not* specify *-CAfile* option to `s_client`. But there is *no* proxy mucking with things. Can you check your Keychain? Make sure `DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA` is present, and make sure *Trust* is set to *Use System Defaults*. Other than that, I am at a loss to explain it because everything looks OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59206/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-jww).

Comment: Just to confirm you mean check the keychain in my iCloud right?

Comment: Are you using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)?

Comment: No I am actually not.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today and after some trial-and-error I determined my repository had just gone over the 1GB threshold. After deleting a junk branch, I was able to push again.