# Mac 10.11 El-Capitan (beta 5) git clone error

Tags: git, macos, osx-elcapitan

I get the following error when running

```
git clone https://www.my-repository.com/myrepo.git MyRepoName
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://www.my-repository.com/myrepo.git':
>   Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   www.my-repository.com:-9850

(repository URL is fictive)

The repository is valid, same command line works fine on 10.10 machine, and same command line used to work before I upgraded to El-Capitan.

Please help...

Nili

Comment: Which git are you using - the one that comes with Xcode, or did you install a newer git from e.g. Homebrew or MacPorts ?

Comment: I also get the same error when trying to pull/fetch an existing repository

Comment: @PaulR I reinstalled git: brew reinstall git. Completed successfully.

Comment: @PaulR I now have git version 2.4.5

Comment: OK - probably just the general vagaries of running a pre-release beta OS - if there is some reason why you need to run 10.11 then consider a dual boot system so that you can do stuff where reliability is important with 10.10 and use 10.11 beta only when necessary. Also try the Apple git that comes with Xcode - it's older but it's more likely to have been tested with 10.11.

Comment: @PaulR how do I try the Apple git? Meaning I need to downgrade / override mine?

Comment: Assuming you've installed Xcode and the Command Line Tools package then the Apple git is at `/usr/bin/git` and the Homebrew git is at `/usr/local/bin/git`. Set your `PATH` accordingly, or use the full path when running git if you just want to try a quick experiment.

Comment: @PaulR Same failure in both :-(

Comment: OK - back to 10.10 then...

Comment: But see this answer for some debugging tips first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20492254/253056

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with Homebrew on 10.11. I was able to overcome them by updating Xcode, GIT, and Homebrew.

Though they do warn that the pre-release version of OS X is not supported, I've found that at this point most packages have been updated.

I updated Xcode through the App Store, then opened it to accept the new terms.

Then at the command line I ran:

```
brew install git
```

Then:

```
brew update
```

I was then back to installing other packages immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
 xcode-select --install
```

It worked for me.