# I'm having issues pushing a commit to bitbucket using SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false 
    -c core.quotepath=false 
    push -v --tags --set-upstream origin Front-end:Web-Pages
fatal: unable to access 

'https://example@bitbucket.org/example/example.git/': 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to bitbucket.org:443 

Pushing to https://example@bitbucket.org/example/example.git

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Please, how do i go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection)

Comment: I'd check the link asap..thanks. @RomCoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution to this problem.

```
$ git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
```

setting the proxy host and port number in git.

Comment: Its what i recommended you to do in step #2 :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Few options:

1. A temporary reply when they have service issues:

   https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/25142498/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-bitbucket.org503
2. You are beyond a proxy
3. Quota limit as suggested in one of the above links. even due i never encored this one my self even when i passed the quota.

---

#### What else can you do?

Verify that you are using the correct SSL configuration:

It should be set to `Open SSH` unless you using putty.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick reply...i'm behind a proxy, i'm using putty too and i have it properly configured.

Comment: Most likely that your proxy is the cause of the error.

Comment: Try to switch to ssh instead of https. It might fix it

Comment: Actually, the SSH/HTTPS connection type wasn't the problem..i solved this by putting my proxy details in git. $ git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
@CodeWizard

Comment: I gave you few options, proxy was one of them :-)