# Git Clone : Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a GitHub project in my office system.

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<UN>:<PWD>@<PROXYSERVER>:<PORT>
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<UN>:<PWD>@<PROXYSERVER>:<PORT>
```

I have set HTTPS and HTTP proxies also set sslVerify to false

```
[https]
    sslVerify = false
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

still, I am getting "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443".

Can someone advise me what do I need to do?

Comment: Is a proxy required? What is your origin? `git remote -v`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use the latest Git (2.12.2) to check if the issue persists.

If it does, see the various settings I mention in "[Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20492254/6309)" in order to debug this:

```
# Windows
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2

# Unix
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2
```

Update Feb. 2018: after [issue 587](https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized/issues/587) (Disable TLSv1.0 and Disable Cipher), this is finally in place: no more TLSv1.0.
See "[Discontinue support for weak cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/)", updated in 2018 with "[Weak cryptographic standards removal notice](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)".

> On February 8, 2018 we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> - **TLSv1/TLSv1.1**: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web, API, and git connections to https://github.com and https://api.github.com.
> - **diffie-hellman-group1-sha1**: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
> - **diffie-hellman-group14-sha1**: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com

So make sure your:

- Git Credential Manager is greater than 1.14.0
- Git on RedHat is (for RedHart) in 7.2 or more
- JDK is 8 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your proxy is set correctly if you have one:
git config --global http.proxy http://User:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT