# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Please help me with this issue..

> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Projects\GIT\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/shadabacc406/test.git +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:
>   stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/shadabacc406/test.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1799)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1525)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:65)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:316)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:513)
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1061)
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)

I added public certificate in github under settings and private key in `jenkins`, but still I'm facing issues.

please help me at the earliest.thanks

Comment: This may be a duplicate. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection

Comment: that is some other repository(bitbucket) Jacob...i tried those settings as well...but still its not working..pls help

Comment: What happens when you try to clone the repo on the Jenkins server from the command line? Also, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: It was proxy issue...thanks Jacob

Comment: You should write exactly what you did to solve your issue and post it here as an answer for others in the future.