# pushing git tag to origin not working tfs 2015

Tags: git, tfs-2015

I am new to git with TFS. I have created a tag in my local git and now I want to push this tag to the remote master. The command I tried is `git push --tags origin`

the error message that I receive is

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://ON_PREM_TFS/tfs/defaultcollection/PROJECT_NAME/_git/GIT-SOLUTION/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ON_PREM_TFS:443
```

I can push and/or sync from Visual Studio without any issue. any clue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  Does your TFS server have a self-signed certificate (or one signed by an internal CA that is not trusted or chained through a generally trusted CA)?

Comment: @mahfuz01 Are you using proxy? If it is ,just try to configure your git proxy, reference this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection

Comment: @EdwardThomson, We are using Visual studio 2015 professional. I am not sure about the certificate issue because it was setup by the infrastructure team and they denied to share this information. :(

Comment: @Andy-MSFT, Yes we are behind a proxy. I will try configuring git proxy and will get back to you at my earliest. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the message, it seems an issue in your network setting then maybe a proxy or a firewall blocking access to the remote repository.

So please check the policy and firewall to make sure the port 443 is accessible.

If the issue persist there after solving the network issue, then try to remove origin and add origin again:

```
git remote -v
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://ON_PREM_TFS/tfs/defaultcollection/PROJECT_NAME/_git/GIT-SOLUTION
```

Then try `git push --tags origin` again.

Comment: @mahfuz01 Have you resolved the issue by configuring the git proxy and the suggestion above? If that works for you, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.