# Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL routines seem to be down

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git (and GitHub) on a daily basis and everything has been working fine and all of a sudden, I can no longer communicate with my remote GitHub repository through my Git commands. When I try to "Git pull", it gives the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/snahrvar/eatibl.git/':
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version

So, I tested across multiple repositories, and I get the same errors on my computer. I had someone else interact with those same repositories, and it works fine for them. Prior to this error, I did an "npm install sharp" on a project and that ended up failing, and I suspect this may have messed with some SSL setting, but that's a wild guess!

Any general thoughts or guidance would be much appreciated!

If it's helpful at all, here is my environment:

- Git version: 1.9.4.msysgit.2
- Windows version: Windows 8.1

Comment: Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection) ?

Comment: Same here with git 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: I believe this change is what caused the error: https://github.com/blog/2507-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed

Comment: I had the same problem and installed Github desktop and everything worked fine!

Comment: There is an official topic from IntelliJ here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/02/26/update-on-ssh-access-to-github-in-intellij-based-ides/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Updating TortoiseGit and GCM didn't help me, but updating Git itself did, as per @Frederic's advice in comments.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

To make sure the new version of Git installs properly and doesn't conflict with previous installations (it might, if you used TortoiseGit's, because it would use different folders and mess with PATH variable), remove the existing Git installation before installing the updated Git. Might also need to install with administrator rights.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened with the last version of git to start throwing these errors today but this answer is it for me. I took a fresh install (2 day old build) and I'm back up and running no ssl errors. Talk about a needle in the haystack.

Comment: The most interesting part is that github themselves aren't mentioning this, even though it's likely related to their recent updates. Quick google search regarding similar problems with other code hostings blames OpenSSL.

Comment: Yep, just needed to update to the latest version! Thanks :D

Comment: Updating didn't resolve my problems! am now getting  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Comment: @gath You probably have 2 incompatible installations of git, try uninstalling the existing one fully, then reinstall git from scratch. But your error is a different one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository

Comment: For me "remove the existing Git installation before installing the updated Git" was the key to this whole debacle.

Comment: updated to the latest version after years, worked like a charm

Answer (score 20):

You're likely running into an incompatibility with GitHub's deprecation of weak SSL encryption protocols:

*[Weak cryptographic standards removal notice](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)*

The solution will vary, but for Windows you likely need to upgrade the Git credential manager to 1.14.0

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0

Comment: Will they continue to support the built-in Git credential manager for windows: wincred. I'm getting the same error with that tool

Comment: This answer helped to provide context about the change, but the solution from @feos is the one that worked for me (Windows 10, TortoiseGit)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, updating Git to [the latest version](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and changing the path to point to the new version solve the problem for me.

[image]

Comment: This also worked for me:  install the latest version of Git and point IntelliJ IDEA to it.

Answer (score 8):

Using TortoiseGit, I did all of the other fixes/updates given for this and still no success. I found this: *[Can't git push/pull/fetch suddenly](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3169)*

My TortoiseGit settings for Git for Windows Git.exe path was pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. I changed it to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and now it's working again.

Comment: I checked it using `Check now` button in `General` settings dialog, with the `x86` path I have get `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1`, after changing to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` I have get `git version 2.16.2.windows.1` and with that path all works fine.

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me.

1. Install the latest version of Git from here: https://git-scm.com/download/win
2. In TortoiseGit, go to menu *Settings* → *General* → *Git.exe Path* - change it from 32-bit to 64-bit path:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin → C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Comment: Good point. If anyone (like me) has been using the old Windows 32-bit version, make sure to replace it on the PATH.

Comment: This saved my time @dgundersen

Answer (score 8):

Updating Git was not enough in my situation. After debugging for several hours, this was my fix:

```
C:\wamp64\www\maandlastenmanager> git config http.sslVersion
tslv1.0

C:\wamp64\www\maandlastenmanager> git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2

C:\wamp64\www\maandlastenmanager> git config http.sslVersion
tslv1.2
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, and on a completely different setup (Mac OS X). `curl` still gives me the message, which makes me wonder if there is a setting like that that goes for all ssl-apps, not just `git`...

Comment: Which one of these lines?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem while pulling code from GitHub on my [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) terminal. I found the advice in the previous answers useful and hacked a solution together following the steps below:

- I [updated Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win).
- I [updated Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0).
- Made some [changes to the registry](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html).
- Updated my Visual Studio Code installation to the latest version.
- Changed my Windows path for Git from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin.` to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

[This repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) was quite useful.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: `git config --system http.sslbackend schannel` and switch off HTTPS checks for `github.com` in your antivirus software**

---

I'm using the Git command line on Windows 8 x64. In addition, **my antivirus software checks HTTPS traffic** by default. Like other people in answering this question, I use GitHub almost daily.

- Updating Git - didn't help - because I used OpenSSL (see below)
- Updating credential manager - didn't help

Then I started playing with switching the SSL backend:

`git config --system http.sslbackend openssl
----------------vs------------------
 git config --system http.sslbackend schannel`

and the antivirus software checks for SSL traffic:

1. OpenSSL, HTTPS checks ON: `error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01`
2. OpenSSL, HTTPS checks OFF: `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`
3. SecureChannel, HTTPS checks ON: `schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.`
4. **SecureChannel, HTTPS checks OFF: worked fine**

P.S.: Instead of commandline, you can just reinstall the latest Git, selecting "Use native Windows SSL validation library".

P.P.S.: The case (3) seems to be a bug in the schannel library, because the MITM certificate my antivirus software uses is whitelisted on my machine.

Comment: When reinstalling git, I completely removed its old installation, and for the new installation, I picked OpenSSL, so I guess it reinstalled it from scratch. But I don't have an antivirus. Did reinstallation of the SSL backend change anything for you, or you didn't do it?

Comment: @feos Yes, it only works for me in non-OpenSSL mode. Plus, I had to turn off https checks in AV.

Comment: It's still unclear to me, did you reinstall SSL  or not?

Comment: @feos No I did not. I don't think one can "reinstall SSL" on Windows. So not sure what you mean by this. When you install latest git client, you have an option to chose - OpenSSL backend or Windows integrated one. I chose OpenSSL. That didn't work and I changed the backend through the configuration. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It does, thanks. I think you were having an entirely different problem than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Same for me with Git 1.9.5.msysgit.1 too. I tried to install https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0, but no change.

Actually, nothing happen after installation; maybe I'm doing something wrong? (That may not help for the initial question, but for other people, yes!)

Comment: Just to help the community, i just updated git (for windows) (with https://git-scm.com/download/win) and it solved the problem !

Comment: Under Windows 7 Pro/64, I upgraded git using the link the git-scm.com/download/win link.  This installed git to c:\program files\git rather than c:\program files (x86)\git.  My version changed from 1.9.5.msysgit.1 to 2.16.2.windows.1 and when I configured WebStorm to point to the newer version, the mysterious _1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version_ error ceased.

Comment: FYI, my setup is: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc> cat install-options.txt
Editor Option: Notepad++
Path Option: Cmd
Plink Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe
SSH Option: Plink
CURL Option: OpenSSL
CRLF Option: CRLFAlways
Bash Terminal Option: MinTTY
Performance Tweaks FSCache: Enabled
Use Credential Manager: Enabled
Enable Symlinks: Disabled`

Comment: You should make your encouragement to upgrade an answer.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, you can [install](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-git-ff00ea12be18) the latest `git` via `Homebrew`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) -- got the same error. I then tried installing `Homebrew` from scratch -- it seems to be a catch22. 

`error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while accessing https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
`

Comment: @Setaa, Well, may be try to install it manually from the Releases page then? They seem have addressed that catch22 in [1.5.5](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/3837)

Comment: If anyone is trying to install git on an older Mac OS X like Snow Leopard, use [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) (a fork of Homebrew specifically intended for supporting older Macs)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I encountered the same issue on a pull request today and the solution was to simply update Git by downloading the latest (2.16.2) 64-bit version of Git for Windows. It was released 5 days ago, on 2018-02-20.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @andw worked for me:

Update Git version 1.9.5 to 2.15.1 using these steps:

In sourceTree, go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Git* → *Use Embedded Git*.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be **git config --global http.sslVerify true**, but it is not recommended as it defeats the purpose using SSL.

A second and better way is to use ssh keys rather than an SSL URL.

**Steps to generate SSH keys**

o Run the following command in a Git terminal (Git Bash): **ssh-keygen**

After running the command, the following message will appear:

**Generating public/private RSA key pair.**

**Enter file in which to save the key (/h//.ssh/id_rsa):**

Give the path for the key to be stored in, for example, enter the file in which to save the key (/h//.ssh/id_rsa): `C:\Users\Public\my-new-ssh-key`

Then give the passphrase for that key (any password of minimum 8 characters)

• Next run the following command: eval  “$(ssh-agent –s)”

• Run the following command: `ssh-add C:/Users/Public/my-new-ssh-key` Note: use forward slash in the path to the newly created SSH key.

After that, add the contents of the file **my-new-ssh-key.pub** and add it in the text area for *Add public key* (Bitbucket, GitHub, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

While connecting to a remote repository to fetch, pull, push, etc., I had the same error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repository.git/': error:1
407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I just reinstalled Git 64-bit in place of 32-bit and that fixed the issue.

After installation, verify the Git path in environment variables. It should be:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with IntelliJ and RubyMine. GitHub must have disabled SSL (PCI compliance maybe?) in favor of TLS. If you open Settings in IntelliJ or RubyMine and navigate to Version Control > Git, you'll see it's using a git.exe installed under the application's path. You should download the most current version of Git and change the path in your VCS settings to point to that, e.g. C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe if you install it on Windows. Works like a charm after that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this is caused by outdated msysgit which is using old ssl and not maintained any more, you can install latest [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), and point the git.exe path in tortoise setting to it, then this problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Git version upgrade did the trick for me. I had the version *1.9.5* and so and I upgraded to *2.21.0* on windows. Also upgrading is very easy. We don't need to uninstall the older version. Download the latest Git installer and just keep on pressing next using default options and the version will be changed to new version and all the old settings will still be working like ssh keys etc. We don't need to generate the keys again and put on github or any other repository.

Earlier my https protocol cloning was not working and giving error

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tensorflow/models/':
>   error:1407742E: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version

Once I downloaded new version and ran the same clone command it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across to this problem recently

What worked for me was to revert an automatic update of `git`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Encountered a similar error. 
On windows, Updated git on windows to the latest version.
That fixed the problem.

Comment: How does this add anything to the accepted answer which suggests updating git to fix the problem?

Comment: I explained what worked for me. Similar to what some others did also perhaps.