# mac 10.7.5 brew update error:1407742E:SSL

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

when I run brew update on mac 10.7.5 I get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': 
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
```

I have run brew install openssl and get

```
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: openssl 1.0.2n is already installed
```

How do I resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: github today changed their HTTPS to require TLSv1.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down and https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/ -- but OpenSSL 1.0.2 should handle TLSv1.2 if brew uses it correctly, and I can't help with that part.

Comment: @Dave - Does it look like Brew is using the old, downlevel version of OpenSSL 0.9.8 supplied with OS X? Shouldn't Brew be using the 1.0.2 version it supplies?

Comment: Homebrew doesn’t use OpenSSL at all since [it has been deprecated by Apple](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/52af92b30786aaa0a3e2fa0b3e60e41d75191591/Formula/openssl.rb#L20).

Comment: I have the exact same error on OS X 10.7.5. I've tried to use MacPorts to install git (version is now 2.17) but I still cannot install homebrew (I uninstalled it earlier). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did someone figure out how to make brew work again?
I also have to use OSX 10.7.5 for a legacy application and i cannot push my source code to GitHub nor update any brew application nor brew itself.
Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: I finally got it working by installing MacPorts and the port 'git-core'.
After that git and openssl had the most recent version and pushing to GitHub was possible again (updating Homebrew as well as a side effect).