# SourceTree error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree and try to clone from a general github repository, but I got this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mfitzp/15-minute-apps.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
>   Completed with errors, see above.

How to solve it?

Comment: Having the same isue with TurtoiseGit since this morning too...

Comment: This happened yesterday and is probably the background to your problem: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL Routines seem to be down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down)

Comment: updating git to latest version worked for me

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Check `Tools > Options > Git` in SourceTree, if you're using `Use Embedded Git`, you can see the git version is `1.9.5` which is  old, [**latest version**](https://git-scm.com/downloads) of git is `2.16.2`.

So click `Use System Git`, if you install the newer version of git, after `Use system Git` it'll show newer version, then try to clone again it should work fine.

Also see another answer [HERE](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html).

[image]

Comment: Upgrade git into the last version helped. Thanks

Comment: Have a similar problem but in Intellj which use a system git.exe of verison 1.9.4.  just upgraded to 2.16.x  latest version. and it solves the problem

Comment: I had not uninstalled the older version before the upgrade and so still saw the issue. Once the older version was uninstalled, it worked for me.

Comment: git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 - is latest version? I installed from Git-2.17.0-64-bit

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem and my fix was:

1.update git to the latest version

2.in command line check your tls version with command: git config http.sslVersion

3.if the version is tlsv1.0 than you have to update it to tlsv1.2 with command:

- git config --global --unset http.sslVersion
- git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2

and than the error won't be present anymore

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. 

Interestingly, when I followed the suggestion from Abed and updated git, it worked, but I got this warning:

warning: unsupported ssl version tslv1.2: using default

Comment: Step1 solved the problem for me `sudo apt-get install git` updates current `git` version

Answer (score 21):

You have to upgrade the git into the last version
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

First, update the git version from https://git-scm.com/downloads

You can install the 32 version and 64 version

Then try to pull the code from the remote repository.

If that doesn't work, run the following command to list all the git configurations

```
git config --global --list
```

Remove all the SSL configuration related settings. 
Remove only SSL configurations, like SSLVersion, etc. You can get the settings name from the above command result. The result format will be
ConfigurationName=value. To remove configurations, run the following command.

```
git config --global --unset ConfigurationName
```

For example, if you want to remove the user.name configuration

```
git config --global --unset user.name
```

After deleting the SSL configurations, try to pull the code from the remote repository. This time the git will use the default SSL configuration values.

Comment: Upgrading to Git-2.16.2-64-bit got rid of the error! - Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First I have installed git version 2.16.
When I type the git version in the terminal, the output is 1.9.
So I uninstalled the old version. And check the git version again, it show me 2.16. The issue resolved, The git works.

Also I have done the following step early, But I don't think this is effective.

```
git config --global --unset http.sslVersion
git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using Mountain Lion (10.8.5) so I can't get a Git version higher than 2.3.5. The only thing that worked for me was to **add an SSH key to my Github account**, as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

And then **cloning with SSH**. Either use SourceTree or just `git clone git@github.com:[username]/[repository].git`

Answer (score 3):

Download new version, it will work like a charm -

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Did not resolve for windows, current git version 2.27.0.windows.1