# Installing Homebrew with Git 1.8.4.2 (Mac OS X 10.7.5)

Tags: git, macos, ssl, homebrew, osx-lion

I'm trying to install Homebrew on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.5), via these two methods:

1. `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git`. The error I get is:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git/':
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version

2. By downloading the .zip archive and running `/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install wget`. Same error:

> error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version while accessing
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

I'm using Git version 1.8.4.2 since I'm on a legacy version of OS X. Is there any way I can tweak the SSL settings to make this work?

TO REITERATE: I am unable to run git higher than 1.8.4.2 because I'm on a legacy OS X. Therefore, telling me to update to a newer version of git kinda shows you didn't read or understand the question in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SourceTree error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23\_GET\_SERVER\_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944875/sourcetree-error1407742essl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-alert-protoc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved by using [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew#tigerbrew).

Answer (score -1):

Update your version of git to at least 2.16.3 due to security protocols removed by github.com