# Failed to install R libraries - SSL issues?

Tags: r, ssl

Everything I try to download a library from R I get "Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"

E.g., I try

install_version("cowplot")

or

remotes::install_github("kassambara/factoextra")

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check that the SSL client and the SSL server have a common combination of protocol / algorithm to start the connection. Otherwise the connection fails.

Note that more and more TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are forbidden by servers (not secure enough): for instance, GitHub has only TLS 1.2 and 1.3.

You can check the server using this online tool: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/5806.

To check the client, you will have to find out which version of OpenSSL is used by your version of R (or maybe provided by the OS). OpenSSL is only a guess: R may also use libcurl, which may be built with [another SSL library](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html), but they all should support TLS 1.2 (at least the recent versions of these libraries).

Upgrading R and/or OpenSSL to the latests versions should solve the issue, but there is another possibility. Note that cowplot is on CRAN [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/), and it has the latest release.

Here you are using `install_version` from [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/). Why not use the builtin R functions for package installation? Set the repository in R using for instance `options(repos="https://cran.r-project.org/")` and install the package with `install.packages("cowplot")`. The main CRAN mirror, https://cran.r-project.org/, supports older versions of TLS (1.0 and 1.1), so it should work.

See also these links:

- https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/
- [SourceTree error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944875/sourcetree-error1407742essl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-alert-protoc)
- [When was TLS 1.2 support added to OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178052/when-was-tls-1-2-support-added-to-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up upgrading through homebrew the entire R distribution including all its dependencies. Call it dependency hell :-)

The part that took the longest and that fixed the problem was that of upgrading to the latest GCC which ends up breaking a number of packages.