# How to download the "clone from github" zip file?

Tags: r, http, github, curl, zip

If I want to download a clone as a zip, it does a redirect.

`zip.url = "https://github.com/MonteShaffer/humanVerse/archive/refs/heads/main.zip"`

redirects to:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://codeload.github.com/MonteShaffer/humanVerse/zip/refs/heads/main">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I am trying to using the `RCurl` library:

```
require(RCurl)
curl.fun = basicTextGatherer();
curl.ch = getCurlHandle();

x = getBinaryURL(zip.url, curl = curl.ch, headerfunction = curl.fun$update )
```

One windoze 10, throwing this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I am assuming github is doing multiple redirects.  I want to download the file as a binary 'zip'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the  curl option `followlocation` to `TRUE`, like this:

```
binary_blob <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(zip.url, .opts = list(followlocation = TRUE))
```

It might be easier to download the file instead with the following two options:

`utils::download.file()` comes with R and works for this.

```
zip.url <- "https://github.com/MonteShaffer/humanVerse/archive/refs/heads/main.zip"

download.file(zip.url, "main.zip")
```

The `curl` package has `curl_download()`.

```
library(curl)
curl::curl_download(zip.url, "main2.zip")
```

Comment: Very nice, comprehensive answer.  I am looking for a ```base::R``` solution.  It downloads the same 1KB redirect file using either `Rcurl` or `download.file` ... I have libcurl enabled.  My codebase would work, but it appears there is something with SSL/TLS going on.  I get the same error using the `followlocation` flag.

Comment: `curl::curl_download()` and `download.file()` both work for me, I get the zip archive (on Linux). I guess something is "special" with your setup.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with my 'git bash' ... Seems unlikely, but ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944875

Comment: Seems like this URL works no problem:  `https://codeload.github.com/MonteShaffer/humanVerse/legacy.tar.gz/main`