# Can't push to origin master

Tags: git, github

I have a private repo on github and it was working up until today and I get this error message when use the command "git push origin master"

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: This is really a question for GitHub support and/or your IT department.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL Routines seem to be down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down)

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has decided today to remove TLS V1 support because it's a weak cryptographic standard.

Depending on your OS/tooling you should update. On Windows, update the Git credential manager.

See the official blog for more information: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/