# 'fatal: HTTP request failed' error when pulling from git repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have been pushing and pulling files to and from my github repositories without problems for the last 4 years. Two days ago, I tried pulling from the repos with the same command i have been using ever since:  `git pull origin master` but i keep getting the error **`"error:  while accessing https://github.com/username/projectname/info/refs . fatal: HTTP request failed"`**. I can push without problems using the command: `git push origin master`. What is the problem here? I tried the suggestions given on some so questions like *`"[Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed]"`* but none has worked. I use the free version of github. Could it be an issue of quota limits for pulls? change in github settings? Or what could be the problem?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938117/7976758) perhaps?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem that is happened because GitHub [Permanently disable deprecated algorithms](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) in February 22, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST)

And I fixed it using : 
     `sudo yum update -y nss curl libcurl`

Comment: still cannot pull

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! It has only just broken, 9 months after the update that you mentioned?! Unless there has been another update this  weekend which I'm unaware of.

Comment: Finally, this fixed it for me. I was attempting to push to Bitbucket on CentOS 6.7 and getting this generic error. Other things I tried before getting here include ensuring name and email were set, changing user in remote URL, setting bitbucket.org IP in /etc/hosts file, updating git, updating root CA certificates, and setting sslVerify to false—nothing else worked. Bitbucket has also just disabled old TLS versions: https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-tlsv1-tlsv1-1-2018-12-01.

Comment: this worked for me.  i'm running git 1.7.1 on a centos 6.x box.

Answer (score 3):

My steps are:

1. Change the git remote url from https to ssh
2. Create ssh key and add to the ssh agent (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)
3. Add the public key to your git repository service account --- By copying the content of the key you generated from 2 into your account settings. We use BitBucket so Settings> SSH keys (under SECURITY) > Add Key (to the key box and save)

Answer (score 0):

After getting the same error, I had to update git on my CentOS 6.5. Because there are no packages newer available through the official repo configured on my OS, I had to :

- install the IUS repository : https://ius.io/GettingStarted/
- remove my actual git install
- install perl-TermReadKey
- install newer version of git :

  ```
  yum install yum --disablerepo=base,updates --enablerepo=ius update git
  ```

Then I was able to push (after it asked me for my username/password Github)