# git pull : info/refs HTTP request failed

Tags: git

I've just logged onto our Prod box (Centos) after a long break, and I can't do `git pull` for some reason.

There seems to be a local problem with this clone of the repo, because I can clone and pull the same repo using the same credentials on other machines (that never had a clone of this repo before)

The command-line message is:

```
[root@ft41 project_folder]# git pull
Password: 
error:  while accessing https://<myusername>@bitbucket.org/<myproject>/<myrepo>.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

The parts in angle-brackets have been redacted by me.
Is this `info/refs` the usual URL for this request?  Could something in the local clone be corrupted and causing this?

If it's helpful:

```
[root@ft41 project_folder]# git status
# On branch master
nothing added to commit
```

Please note - I have done `git pull` from this pc/directory successfully many times in the past.  It does support HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be because of the [very recent disabling of TLSv1 and TLSv1.1](https://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/7h6w4t2xczc0)  done by BitBucket ([GitHub had done that in Feb. 2018](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/))

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49026601/6309), do upgrade  nss, curl and libcurl (see [here for an example of curl upgrade on CentOS](https://serverfault.com/a/775576/783)).

```
sudo yum update -y nss curl libcurl
```

Comment: it worked! If anyone has this issue try `sudo yum update -y nss curl libcurl` Saved you a click ;)

Comment: i am facing the same issue in Rhel6.9 but i am unable to update nss curl libcurl. any idea?

Comment: @user11668570 Simply download the rpms for [nss](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-updates-x86_64/nss-3.44.0-7.el6_10.i686.rpm.html), [curl](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/curl-7.19.7-53.el6_9.x86_64.rpm.html) and [libcurl](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/libcurl-7.19.7-53.el6_9.x86_64.rpm.html) in `/home/<me>/mycurl` (any path you want). Use `rpm2cpio <file.rpm>| cpio -idmv` to unzip them, and add `/home/<me>/mycurl/bin` to your `PATH`. Add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<me>/mycurl/usr/lib64`.

Answer (score 0):

Also may happen when using outdated git CLI. Trying the same commands on more recent version helped me to resolve the issue.