# Ubuntu git: fatal: unable to access gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssl, bitbucket

I am trying to run a simple git pull command in  my ubuntu. It used to work perfectly until a few days ago. Not it shows 
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/reponame/project.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.

I've tried several things that I found in this forum but nothing has worked so far.
Thanks!

Note: 
I tried doing what was listed in the solutions mentioned but it is not working. I need to be able to run a git pull from my server.

If it helps the version of my curl is 7.50.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull : info/refs HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625669/git-pull-info-refs-http-request-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbitbucket%5d%20%5bgit%5d%20ssl

Comment: Those solutions do not seem to be working

Comment: Can you mention what version of Ubuntu you're using and what version of Git you're using?

Comment: And what version of GnuTLS, please.

Comment: My Ubutu Version is 
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04

Comment: git version 2.9.5
I don't know how to check GnuTLS version :(

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded git to version 2.20 and now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, my git version is 2.19.x, after i run the following :
#add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa

## apt-get update; apt-get install git

i cannot upgrade git to new version, so i fetched the source code of 2.22.1 from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/, and remove old get, make and make install, upgrade git to 2.22.1, fixed this problem, git works well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).