# BitBucket Git - fatal: unable to access ... SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have tried everything I could find in documentation on the BitBucket site and in YouTube videos etc, and nothing seems to fix the error listed in title of my question.  I have generated the keys and placed the public on the site and set up the local SourceTree to use the private one and the putty option.  I have tried all details I could find and nothing effects the error.  Please help and with all due respect if all you're going to do is point me to other question please don't waste my time.  I have spent all day looking at other questions.  Thanks.
Edit:  someone claimed this question had already been answered, but if you see their comment the error they mention that is addressed in the other question is clearly not the same error message I received, so they are wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull : info/refs HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625669/git-pull-info-refs-http-request-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbitbucket%5d%20ssl

Comment: My question does not duplicate the question you listed.  They received the error "fatal: HTTP request failed".  The error I received was different as the title of my question shows.  You just enjoy down voting other people's questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this error for most of a day, it turns out that all it was was due to the Embedded option not being selected under the Tools/Options/Git menu.  For some reason they include an Embedded Git in their tool but they default to use your already installed Git on your computer.  So, if you do like I did and follow all of the steps to install he keys etc, it will not help you since any previously installed git once be configured the way they want it (i guess).  The second I clicked Embedded to tell it to use the embedded git that comes with their tool, everything started working and I was able to push my local git repo up to the one I had created on BitBucket.  I have included a picture below.  I will leave this question in case this detail helps someone else since I'm guessing I'm not the only person to get stuck on this detail.
[image]