# Bitbucket: git push stopped working: "fatal: HTTP request failed"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working with my git repo on BitBucket in the simplest way: I sometimes commit changes and immediately push them in to the master branch.

it worked for 2 years; but during last month I can commit and I cannot push:

> $ git push
>
> Password:
>
> error:  while accessing https://mylogin@bitbucket.org/mylogin/myproject.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

I didn't change any repo settings. I am the admin of this repo.

Any ideas what can help here?
Thank you!

Comment: This is due to a connection problem between your machine and the git repository. I suggest you look into your internet connection settings, such as things like proxy or VPN that may affect this.

Comment: I think I am not using any proxies or VPNs

Comment: It could also be a moved or renamed repository on Bitbucket.

Comment: The link to the project is still https://bitbucket.org/mylogin/myproject

Comment: Can you verify that push url is correct with `git remote -v`? Try make a new local clone of the repo and push from that (try cloning with SSH and HTTPS)

Comment: The method described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972956/fatal-http-request-failed-error-when-pulling-from-git-repository/49026601#49026601 helped!

Answer (score 0):

RKN problems may be, Alexey. Try proxy/vpn.

Comment: I am currently in the US.)