# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, openssl

I used git "push" and "pull" commands with success till yesterday, but today it is not working and give me this error: `Push failed: Unable to access 'https://github.com/username/repository.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443`

I tried many solutions but no success.
Solutions I tried:
1. Using SSH key
2. Updating git
3. Installing curl with openssl (same error while installing)

This is the result of `curl github.com -v`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: github.com/
*   Trying 192.30.253.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem was solved by restarting my computer.

Update: 
Kaspersky Internet Security/Antivirus causes the problem and disabling/removing it fixes the issue for most users.

Comment: Thanks @EsmatullahArifi,
this solved my problem (probably relate to the fact that my Mac was just updated and didn't get a proper restart)

Comment: It's not a solution it's a workaround, it keeps happening over and over. I'm looking for a solution for it

Comment: Sigh! Me too. Thanks.

Comment: Me three... It works right after a restart but eventually, I get the connection error again. I haven't been able to pin down what causes it.

Comment: @Abhisheksaharn we end up discoverying it is a problem with Kaspersky. We migrated to anoter ant-virus as we could not get anyhelp from them.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino thanks for the update. It disabling/removing Kaspersky worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

We started an investigation internally and we discovered that in our case was a problem with Kaspersky antivirus.

We raised a bug for their support, waited, waited, got feedback that would be solved some months ago in a new release. We got and tried the release, the problem was still there. We raised again another ticket, a lot of debugging information/files they requested. Still not solved.

We gave up and moved to Avast, no problems so far.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! I tried different pod versions, reinstalling git and curl and what not, turned out it was Kaspersky :)

Comment: If you have Kaspersky Antivirus installed, try to disable HTTPS inspection in it, this may be sufficient to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As commented in [libressl-portable/portable/issue 369](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/369#issuecomment-359373819)

> I update with brew, libressl, openssl and curl and reboot my machine. It's now working.

Note that SSH should work, but for that you need to change your origin URL

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:aUser/aProject
```

That would not use HTTPS at all then.

Comment: How to update the brew? while I update the brew this is the output `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443  `

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi Not "update the brew", update with brew: are you on Mac? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am using macOS Mojave and there is no proxy. I am directly connected to internet, I tested different internet connections.

Comment: I already have it. This is the result of `brew -v`: `Homebrew 1.3.1-4356-g6d393de
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 84a8; last commit 2017-08-24)`

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi Check if it the latest by typing `brew update`

Comment: @EsmatullahArifi with your current version of brew, can you try and update  libressl, openssl and curl ? Or would that fail with the same error message?

Comment: And using https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544596/6309 (`networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi`)? or trying and reinstall curl with opensll instead of libressl? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798271/6309)

Comment: this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443/49798271#49798271] is showing same error but the other link solution was not successful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181586/discussion-between-vonc-and-esmatullah-arifi).

Comment: Tried reboot first, it works for me without updating anything!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, by restarting my Mac, i could push my code to Github and the error message was gone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the new git repo is just created and I do push some code and then get this issue.
I try to run `git pull` first and run `git push` after that. Then everything works well, didn't get the root cause.
Operation: macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a issue with you network connection. Try to clone the repo using git command and check if that's successful.

eg:

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;` if you are using a proxy (Change the value for your own need).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,
The issue was with vpn
Disabling vpn worked for me hope this will be helpful