# Installing Homebrew for python on Mac

Tags: python, homebrew

I am working through a book to learn python on version 2.7. I need to download homebrew as part of a project in the book. As required, from homebrew's website, I paste the following in terminal...

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

...but I get the following error:

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443
```

I have been researching, trying to find answers to this for a while now. From what I have read, it seems my problem is I can not connect to raw.gihubusercontent.com. To check, when I type that url into my browser, it says:

> This site can’t be reached
>   raw.githubusercontent.com unexpectedly closed the connection.

From my research, it seems like I need to download a proxy, as that is what the following link implied: [link 1](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/46280). But it provides info on how to do it when working behind a proxy, from what I understand.

According to [this website](http://amibehindaproxy.com/) I am not behind a proxy, as some threads suggested this problem could stem from. So, how do I fix this problem and install homebrew? I am not the most computer-savvy person, so if I am missing information here, please let me know, I will be checking this thread around the clock. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!! :)

If it matters: I am on macOS HighSierra version 10.13.2, and XCode is fully updated.

Comment: What country are you in? Can you reach http://github.com in a browser?

Comment: Hi @DanielPryden ! I am in the United States. I can reach github.com in a browser.

Comment: A couple of things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48987512/7954504

Comment: OK so it worked itself out! I was doing my work at a coffee shop and when I got home on my own internet it worked no problem.