# How to configure github with proxy?

Tags: github, proxy, git-config

I am running through a proxy and i do not understand how to make git work.If i try to clone a repo i get the following error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/somerepo
```

> Cloning into '[something]'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/somerepo': OpenSSL SSL_connect:
>   SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

I have already tried most of what it is saying here [changing the git global](https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765) and checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443?rq=1) thread too to no avail.
I have also tried to unset proxy for http and https.

Looking in my git config it looks like this:

```
[user]
        name = Adri
        email = [some_address]@outlook.com
[http]
        sslBackend = openssl
        sslCAInfo = C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\ssl\\cert.pem
[remote "origin"]
        proxy =
```

Could this be a problem ?

**P.S** I get this problem for all git operations, i can't clone,pull,push etc.. and for all repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Comment: Also try https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765