# How do I push commits to Github?

Tags: android-studio, github

I want to make a push to my own private Github repository and I get the following error message:

```
Unable to access 'https://github.com/Kaisercoding/GuessIt.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

I already added a ssh key to my project but the error still occurs.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL\_connect: SSL\_ERROR\_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443)

Answer (score 0):

Without an error log, try updating with brew, libressl, and openssl, reboot the machine, and try again.