# Github fetch failed with error : update failed unable to access and SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: git, github, repository, git-pull

I am not able to fetch my GitHub repository in local machine.

Following error getting:

```
Update failed           
unable to access 'https://github.com/codewithvikas/Exploring-Android.git/': 
LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

Note: I have found similar question but not got any satisfactory answer.

Edit1:

It works when i restart my system and anti-virus is updated. So is it problem with my Anti-virus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your platform (OS version) and Git version.

Make sure sure to:

- upgrade to the latest Git 2.24
- check in your PATH that Git installation is considered first.
- check your proxy or that you are not using ipV6, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48987512/6309).

The [OP CodeWithVikas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5165107/codewithvikas) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797497/github-fetch-failed-with-error-update-failed-unable-to-access-and-ssl-error-sy/58798433?noredirect=1#comment104165244_58798433) an Antivirus issue.

Comment: everything is fine. one clue i found is when i restart my system it works. so have to restart my system daily.

Comment: What system is this? What OS? What version?

Comment: MacOS Mojave
version 10.14.6

Comment: @CodeWithVikas Did you figured it out?

Comment: Yes. Problem was my Antivirus was not working. And ipV6 issue is due to this only i think.

Comment: @CodeWithVikas Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.