# Error in Cloning Laravel Homestead

Tags: git, laravel, git-bash, homestead

I'm trying to clone laravel homestead but this error is showing.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
Cloning into 'c:/Users/Kay/Homestead'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

What is this error? I'm using Git Bash on a windows environment. The version is  1.9.4.msysgit.2.

Comment: don't use ~/Homestead

Comment: @AmmarAli why is that? The Laravel documentation says that Homestead is the recommended environment.for Local development

Comment: Yep, it's recommended environment. After clone use command `composer update` it'll fix all your problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL routines seem to be down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by updating Git Bash.

I was using an outdated one.