# Trouble pushing project to github

Tags: git, github

I seem to be having trouble pushing a ruby on rails project to github. Below is a link to the screen I'm getting. Any help is appreciated.

https://github.com/alexanderross936/git5/blob/master/20181006_121111.jpg

Comment: The link only shows `This file is too big to show. Sorry!` However, you should provide any error message in text in your question.

Comment: Could you give more info. about the issue as it is not clear from your questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL routines seem to be down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+alert+protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "tlsv1 alert protocol error" means that you tried to connect to the remote server (in this case, GitHub), but your TLS version is too old.  GitHub requires the use of TLS 1.2 to connect, since older versions are insecure, and whatever version of Git you're using was linked against a TLS library that doesn't support TLS 1.2.

If you want to continue to use HTTPS, you need to find a version of Git that's linked against a crypto library that supports TLS 1.2.  You haven't specified what environment you're using, so I can't be more specific.  Alternately, you could use SSH to interact with GitHub, which might work better for you.