# Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError when using Inquisition gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

As per the client suggestion, I am using inquisition gem in my Rails 5.0 application. I followed this [link](https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition) and added gem in Gemfile and ran  bundle, I got the  following error:

> E:\rails_projects\inquisition_example>bundle Fetching
>   https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition.git fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition.git/': error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
>
> Retrying `git clone "https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition.git"
>   "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/inquisition-40e0b17fff1501354aa91e3ff3bbb85f990b5f49"
>   --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone
>   "https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition.git"
>   "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache/bundler/git/inquisition-40e0b17fff1501354aa91e3ff3bbb85f990b5f49"
>   --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory E:/rails_projects/inquisition_example has failed. fatal: unable to
>   access 'https://github.com/rubygarage/inquisition.git/':
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version

Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull / push - unable to access HTTPS, SSL routines seem to be down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+SSL+routines%3ASSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO%3Atlsv1+alert+protocol+version

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the OpenSSL version you are using in Git's libcurl is too old. GitHub only supports TLS 1.2 and 1.3, and the version of OpenSSL that libcurl is compiled with doesn't know how to negotiate those versions.

Since it looks like you're using Windows, you should update Git for Windows to the latest version, which will include an updated version of OpenSSL and libcurl so Git will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on my project and I solved it by updating git version. Below are the steps:

1. Ensure that you are using the latest git version
2. Add the git PPA using the terminal and update git using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
Sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

I hope this helps, Happy codding.