# Cannot clone git repository via Git Bash

Tags: git, github, openssl, certificate

While trying to clone a repository using `git clone`, it shows the following error:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/microsoft/c9-python-getting-started.git/': OpenSSL
>   was built without SSLv2 support

Using the latest `Git 2.23.0` on `Windows 10 x64 Home Single Language`

Just initiated my Git journey, please help me past this roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following lines from `[http]` header of `.gitconfig` file:

```
sslVersion = sslv3
sslVersion = sslv2
```

and it is working now with https

Answer (score 3):

I just cloned it on my own W10 x64 PC without any issue

```
D:\git>git version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1

D:\git>git clone https://github.com/microsoft/c9-python-getting-started/
Cloning into 'c9-python-getting-started'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 166, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (166/166), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (136/136), done.

Receiving objects: 100% (166/166), 3.11 MiB | 1.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (30/30), done.
```

Try and unzip [`PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.23.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and see if setting a simplified PATH (just for testing, in a CMD session) helps:

```
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/c9-python-getting-started/
```

Of course, you might have the alternative: clone with the SSH URL

```
git clone git@github.com:microsoft/c9-python-getting-started.git
```

But it is more interesting to first understand why HTTPS fails.

[phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047250/cannot-clone-git-repository-via-git-bash/58047336?noredirect=1#comment102494962_58047336) a proxy issue, as one illustrated in [`curl/curl` issue 1433](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1433).

I mention in "[Unknown SSL protocol error in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20492254/6309)" various way to debug flaky connections, including the Q3 2015 Git 2.6 `http.sslVersion` setting, to force `sslv3`.

Comment: I suspect there is an HTTPS proxy between the OP and Github. The proxy seems to be using outdated protocol SSLv2.

Comment: @phd I though SSLv2 was still supported. I know of https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: The link mentioned in the last para contains helpful information. Now I only have tlsv1.3 in http.sslversion