# How to check if commit first letter is uppercase with githooks

Tags: githooks

I have validation statement (full githooks commit-msg):
    #!/bin/sh

```
read -r message<$1

if [[ $text =~ ^[a-z] ]]
then
    printf "$warning Check commit message.\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

When I make commit with text: "This is my test commit", githooks responds with:

```
[WARNING] Check commit message.
```

But when I make it with something like this: "this is my test commit", I get tge same result.

What an I doing wrong?

I am using Wind10, Git version 2.20.1.windows.1 and GitBash.

Comment: That does not look like the full content: you are missing at least the first line (`#!/bin/sh)`. if you had not included this line in your script, can you try again after adding this line, in a CMD session, with a simplified PATH?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested such a [similar hook](https://githooks.com/), but using the **`commit-msg`**, *not* the `pre-commit` one.
(Git 2.23, Windows 10, CMD session)

```
myrepo/.git/hooks/commit-msg

#!/bin/sh

echo "1='$1'"
cat $1
if [[ $(cat $1) =~ ^[a-z] ]]
then
    printf "$warning Check commit message.\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

It works as advertised: if your commit message starts with a lowercase, it will block the commit creation:

```
D:\git\rr>git add .

D:\git\rr>git commit -m "aaa"
aaa
 Check commit message.
```

The **`commit-msg`** hook receives `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` as first parameter.

With an upercase first-letter, it will work:

```
D:\git\rr>git commit -m "Aaa"
Aaa
[master 222cffb] Aaa
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Comment: Same thing is happening when I am trying with uppercase, like "Test commit". My goal was block if commit text start with lowercase and allow uppercase. But this check will drop everything whit lowercase and upercase.

Comment: @Developer The point of the answer is to illustrate it will *not* with a pre-commit hook, but only with commit-msg hook.

Comment: @Developer I have edited the answer to show it *will work* with an uppercase.

Comment: @Developer because you might using a pre-commit hook, instead of a commit-msg hook: what is your hook file name and path?

Comment: I am using commit-msg and location: .git\hooks\commit-msg

Comment: @Developer Did you try the exact content that I mention in the answer? For instance, you cannot use `$1` directly, you need to read (`cat`) the `$1` reference to access the message. In your question, I do not see how "`$text`" was initialized.

Comment: @Developer try with the code I suggest in the answer: it should work.

Comment: With your code: $ git commit -am "test message"
Checking code style...
1='.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
test message
 Check commit message.
AND SECOUND:$ git commit -am "Test message"
Checking code style...
1='.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
Test message
 Check commit message.

Comment: @Developer Strange. Can you check with Git 2.23?

Comment: Same thing with 2.23 version as well.

Comment: @Developer Can you check that in a regular CMD shell session (no git bash) with a simplified PATH? (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047336/6309)

Comment: @Developer Can you also edit your question with the full complete content of your commit-msg hook?

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl try with:

```
^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9 -]*
```

You current regex checks for single letter lower case.

Comment: I tried but this did not worked. I get same response when my message started with uppercase or lowercase.